# Import excel files in Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, ubuntu

I have number of excel files that I want to import in Matlab R2011a version in Ubuntu. I am not able to proceed and end up with error

```
Warning: Could not start Excel server for import, 'basic' mode will be used. Refer to HELP XLSREAD for more information. 
> In xlsread at 175
  In PCT_DART at 38"
```

Is there any package or something that should be done because the excel files are of big size and 'basic' mode would not be sufficient to extract all the datas from files.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, annoying isn't it?

the Mathworks were more or less forced to decide to use the MS COM server for importing Excel files that contain anything more "advanced" than plain data on a single sheet. A *severe* ramification of this decision is that all Linux and Mac users will get this error, and will experience limited import capability when data is spread over multiple sheets, the Excel file contains graphs, etc.

There is not much you can do here if you want to leave the Excel files untouched. "Fortunately", many people have struggled with this. Have a look [here](http://www.mathworks.nl/matlabcentral/answers/14817), for example, where it is suggested to try and save the Excel file in an older format (say, Excel 98/95) and try again.

What I usually do is just copy-paste or export the data I need into plain-text CSV, and be done with trying to `try...catch...end` errors like these in cross-platform Matlab code. Ideally, this is already done on the data generation end; if it is at all possible to generate your data in plain-text format instead of XLS, do it.

Comment: Yes, +1, and I would add that you can export XLS from excel directly to CSV.